# Getting `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` by getting ClipboardManager in ReactContextBaseJavaModule

Tags: java, android, react-native

Hi I've tried to search similar problems but mine is a bit tricky. I extended a `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` and initiated a `ClipboardManager` by following this official tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

Here is the code for my extended class:

```
public class ClipBoardIntercepter extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements LifecycleEventListener {

protected  @Nullable
ClipboardManager mClipboard;

protected @Nullable
ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener;

private boolean disableCopy = true;
private boolean disableCopyBackup = true;

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "ClipBoardIntercepter";
}

public ClipBoardIntercepter(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    reactContext.addLifecycleEventListener(this);

    this.mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    //subscribe to clipboard manager
    initializeClipboardListener();
    subscribeClipboardManager();
}

@Override
public void onHostResume() {
    //subscribeClipboardManager();
    this.disableCopy = this.disableCopyBackup;
}

@Override
public void onHostPause() {
    //unsubscribeClipboardManager();
    this.disableCopy = false;
}

@Override
public void onHostDestroy() {
    //unsubscribeClipboardManager();
    this.disableCopy = false;
}

private void initializeClipboardListener() {
    //init OnPrimaryClipChangedListener and register
    mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener = new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
            String defaultString = "Please subscribe to essayBot";
            //only when disableCopy is true and clipboard data has not been programmatically set
            if (disableCopy && !isClipBoardDataSetToDefault(mClipboard, defaultString)) {
                mClipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText(null, "Please subscribe to essayBot"));
                dispatchOnPasteboardChanged();
            }
        }
    };
}

private void subscribeClipboardManager() {
    mClipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);
}

private void unsubscribeClipboardManager() {
    mClipboard.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);
}



private Boolean isClipBoardDataSetToDefault(ClipboardManager clipboard, String defaultString) {
    // if clipboard has data and data is plain text
    if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip() && clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
        ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
        String clipboardText = item.getText().toString();
        return defaultString.equals(clipboardText);
    }

    //default is false
    return false;
}

private void dispatchOnPasteboardChanged() {
    WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
    ReactApplicationContext reactContext = this.getReactApplicationContext();
    reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("onPasteboardChanged", event);
}

@ReactMethod
public void setDisableCopy(Boolean disablePasteboard) {
    disableCopy = disablePasteboard;
    disableCopyBackup = disablePasteboard;
}
```

}

It works perfectly fine on Android 9.0 on both virtual and real devices. However, I'm getting `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` on devices with versions lower than that:

[image]

I've read posts that suggest putting the initialization in a handler:

```
//get ClipboardManager
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        }
    });
```

However, this way creates an inner class and I'd need to have a reference to the initialized `ClipboardManager`

I have two questions:

1. What other workarounds I can do here?
2. Why is this error happening? I initialized a system service just as how the tutorial said to use `Toast` and I'm only getting errors for Android versions below 9.0

Comment: To me this happened when I instantiated the handler as a class member. I moved it inside a method and called this from other event and it was working fine

Comment: That worked. Thanks @petrumo